# Installing sqlite gem fails on AWS Linux instance with sqlite-devel libraries installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, amazon-ami

I'm running an instance built off ami-595a0a1c. I am trying to install the sqlite3 (or sqlite) gem and it's failing with the below error:

> ```
> $ sudo gem install sqlite3
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR: Error installing sqlite3:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> checking for sqlite3.h... no
> sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
> or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path
> ```
>
> (the
>       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
>       extconf.rb failed ***
>       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>       necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for
>   more
>       details. You may need configuration options.
>
> ```
> Provided configuration options:
> --with-opt-dir
> --without-opt-dir
> --with-opt-include
> --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> --with-opt-lib
> --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
> --with-make-prog
> --without-make-prog
> --srcdir=.
> --curdir
> --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
> --with-sqlite3-dir
> --without-sqlite3-dir
> --with-sqlite3-include
> --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
> --with-sqlite3-lib
> --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
> Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection. Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
> ```

Typically, this just means you need to install the development libraries and everything is cool. However, I have installed the sqlite-devel packages and still no dice. Since this is the Amazon Linux instance, I'd rather not add more repositories than the ones Amazon provides if possible.  What can i do to get this thing to compile? Thanks for any insight!

From a brand new instance, here's what I've done:

> $ sudo yum install rubygems ruby-devel
>
> $ sudo gem update --system
>
> $ sudo gem install rails
>
> $ rails new app
>
> $ cd app
>
> $ rails server
>
> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
>
> $ sudo yum install sqlite-devel
>
> $ sudo gem install sqlite (or sqlite3 -- same result)

See breakage above

Answer (score 1):

I just tested today on AWS' AMI. Same problem at first when trying to install the sqlite3 gem. Tried as told by the installer, no luck. However, I tried

```
sudo gem install sqlite-devel
```

and it worked, could install the sqlite3 gem after that...

Hoping it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I guess this answer on stackoverflow will also help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015766/issues-with-rails-on-ec2-when-calling-build-install/9050566#9050566